# Topology of a module of finite type

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, topological-vector-spaces, galois-representations

In 'Theory of p-adic Galois representations' (Fontaine-Ouyang), given a topological commutative ring B equipped with a continuous compatible action of a topological group G the authors define: A $\textbf{B-representation}\; X$ of $G$ to be  a $B$-module of finite type equipped with a continuous and semi-linear action of $G$.

My question is when we are talking about the continuous action of $G$ on $X$ are we giving $X$ the quotient topology it inherits from the surjection $B^d\rightarrow X$ for some $d$, where $B^d$ is given the product topology. If so, then is it  obvious that the topology does not depend on the choice of the surjection?

Similarly when we tensor $B$ representations, I don't see a natural way of equipping  it with a topology, in case $B$ is a field, then do we equip it with the topology of $B^n$ for example?

I don't know whether I am missing something obvious or if this is a stupid question.

Comment: I would assume that a "$B$-module" is just any topological abelian group $X$ together with a continuous map $B\times X\to X$ that satisfies the axioms of scalar multiplication.  But maybe the definition is more restrictive in this context, or "finite type" is supposed to also say something about the topology.

Comment: An alternative guess: it's a fairly standard fact that if $B$ is a Noetherian Banach algebra over a non-archimedean valued field, which covers a lot of the rings which are relevant in Fontaine--Ouyang, then any finitely-generated abstract $B$-module has a "canonical topology", which is the topology induced by any choice of surjection $B^d \to X$. So it may be that they mean "continuous with respect to the canonical B-module topology on X" or something like that.

Comment: In most of the situations that I have encountered so far in that book, X comes with a natural topology. Is it because the topology is clear from the concrete situation we should not bother about it beforehand?